# How to insert page break in Aspose.PDF XSLT

Tags: xslt, pdf-generation, aspose, aspose.pdf

I am writing XSLT to be used with XML in Aspose.PDF to generate the PDF, how do I insert the page break in the Aspose.PDF XSLT?

I have tried #$NP but it doesn't seem to be working, or my syntax is not correct.

```
<TextFragment>
    <TextSegment>#$NP</TextSegment>
</TextFragment>
```

I have also tried to split the document by having a multiple page tags.

```
 <Page>...</Page>
```

But that also didn't seem to work, and Aspose was actually throwing an error when I tried that, so what would be the correct way?

I would like to be able to insert the page break after each section of the PDF. Also any links to some advanced Aspose.PDF XSLT examples will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

For the old Aspose.PDF versions, please, try this way:

```
<Text>
   <Segment>
     <!--Page Breaker-->
     #$NP
   </Segment>
</Text>
```

For the latest Aspose.PDF versions, please, try this way:

```
<Page>
   <TextFragment>
      <TextSegment>
         First page.
      </TextSegment>
   </TextFragment>
</Page>
<Page>
   <TextFragment>
      <TextSegment>
         Second page.
      </TextSegment>
   </TextFragment>
</Page>
```

Hope it helps. Otherwise, feel free to ask me.

**Note**: I am working as Developer Evangelist at Aspose.

Comment: I am using the 
Aspose.PDF for .NET 19.4, unfortunately Aspose throws the error: `Unhandled Exception: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
   at Aspose.Pdf.Page.#=zvjHewFY=(XmlReader #=zNI6$7Kk=)
   at Aspose.Pdf.Document.BindXml(Stream stream)
   at Aspose.Pdf.Document.BindXml(Stream xmlStream, Stream xslStream, XmlReaderSettings settings)
   at Aspose.Pdf.Document.BindXml(Stream xmlStream, Stream xslStream)
   at kentec.PDFGenerator.Generator..ctor(String[] args)
   at kentec.PDFGenerator.PDFGenerator.Main(String[] args)`

Comment: Please, take a look at the updated answer. Thank you.

Comment: Thank you for editing your answer, the '<Page>...</Page>' works and the content appears on the new page, however the '#$NP' is definitely not working and has no effect on the content, perhaps it is a bug in Aspose.PDF.

Comment: @Kugarek, Thanks for noticing, you are right #$NP is not necessary anymore, <Page>...</Page> is enough. Thank you